# Java containsAll returns wrong index from multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been testing my class when I came up with this problem. I tried everything but it seems I can't find any solution. Here is my `pseudo code:`

```
String[] pastaRecipe = {a, b, c, d, e};
String[] saladRecipe = {f, g, h, i, j};
String[][] finalRecipes = {pastaRecipe, saladRecipe};

String[] testInput = {a, b, c, d, e};

    if (pastaRecipe contansAll testInput) then
        print You coulds cook a pasta
    end
```

> Here's my Implementation:

```
public class RecipeTest() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

            String[] porkSteak = {"Pork", "Garlic", "Dried bay leaves", "Vinegar", "Soy sauce", "Whole pepper corn", "Salt"};
            String[] porkSoup = {"Pork", "String Beans", "Vinegar", "Soy sauce", "Whole pepper corn", "salt"};
            String[][] finalRecipes = {porkSteak, porkSoup};


            String[] testInput = {"Pork", "Garlic", "Dried bay leaves", "Vinegar", "Soy sauce", "Whole pepper corn", "Salt"};

            for (int i = 0; i < finalRecipes.length; i++) {

                if(Arrays.asList(testInput).containsAll(Arrays.asList(finalRecipes[i]))) {

                    results.add(finalRecipes[i][finalRecipes.length - 1]);

                }
            }

            System.out.println("You can cook " + results.get(0));

    }
}
```

> My output:
>           You can cook salt
>
> Expected output:
>           You can cook pork steak.

Comment: How do you expect the output to be `pork steak`? Your pseudo code doesn't make much sense either...

Comment: Do you mean to return the *name* of the array, `porkSteak` or ..?

Comment: Your sample code (apart that it does not compile since your `try` doesnt have `catch` clause) returns to me `You can cook Garlic`

Comment: Yes yea i want to return the name of the recipe.

Comment: `containsAll` doesn't return an index, it returns `boolean` based on whether the list in question contains all elements from the second list.

Comment: I meant if its true it will return the name of the recipe. I'm sorry if  theres no catch clause i'm only using a tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work with the least amount of work, you would have to create an array of recipe names and keep it in sync with the `finalRecipes` array. E.g.

```
String[][] finalRecipes = {porkSteak, porkSoup};
String[] recipeNames = {"Pork Steak", "Pork Soup"};
```

And then use it in the `if`

```
if (Arrays.asList(testInput).containsAll(Arrays.asList(finalRecipes[i]))) {
    results.add(recipeNames[i]);
}
```

But ideally, you'd want to create a `Recipe` class, which would contain a list of ingredients and its name.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you very much for the help. Sorry for misleading title.